# Jquery slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Hi I am working right now on the custom slider that enlarge the central pictures when clicking on the next button and put back the same size when clicking on previous button. To see I am trying to make a slide like the IOS music album gallery. The problem with my slide is that after a few clicking it is not enlarging or reducing the pictures size and only enlarge the central picture by reducing the right and left pictures. Here is my code, if you can help me out to solve this problem. you can test it here  jsfiddle.net/jdDYQ/4

HTML :

```
<ul class="mf1_ui" style="width: 3355.582507916454px; left: -1770.83984375px;">
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5333/9509968984_39f271e72e_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f30_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7320/9507172741_b869095bb1_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f29_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5328/9507168757_22b6b7fc4c_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f28_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2830/9509968588_b11cc4d925_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f27_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3758/9509964156_684f190b8a_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f25_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7433/9509965790_b6103e5431_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f24_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3778/9509963902_af7174270c_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f22_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2834/9507172221_0a9061158e_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f18_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3687/9507172565_4c16634337_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f23_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3814/9507167983_0b9f412f24_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f21_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7367/9509967948_dedf14f137_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f20_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3713/9509963520_97e8412f2f_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f19_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2829/9509963108_88692d54aa_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f17_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 146px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3727/9507171935_623a1cef78_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f16_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 106px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5517/9509967638_2a437768ff_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f15_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 106px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7319/9509962870_4448372911_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f14_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 106px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3685/9507167175_f9e5c96464_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f13_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 106px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2890/9507171303_c02425f931_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f12_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 106px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5452/9509967070_dbd6860dfd_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f11_li" style="height: 88px; display: inline-block; width: 106px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2859/9509962588_5161ca44cf_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f10_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3823/9509962656_c09647f4d9_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f9_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2883/9509962418_8439045748_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f8_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2850/9507166999_d48c875c07_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f7_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2875/9507170425_0f1de921c1_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f6_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2885/9509965594_7a93eef0fc_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f5_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3727/9509965018_b07c0afedf_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f4_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5501/9507168951_b375e733f5_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f3_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7369/9509962244_978bbbc34e_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f2_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2853/9507166807_44ba87d059_m.jpg" alt="" class="mf1_f1_li" style="height: 88px;">
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript/jQuery :

```
'[class*="next"] click': function (el, ev) {
    var cName = el.attr('class').substr(5);
    var slideId = cName.substring(0, cName.lastIndexOf("_"));
    //var bigWidth = $("."+slideId+"_ui li img").width() + 28;
    //console.log(bigWidth);

    if (-(parseInt($("." + slideId + "_ui").css("left"), 10)) < (parseInt($("." + slideId + "_ui").css("width"), 10) - 288)) {

        $('.' + slideId + '_' + 'ui').animate({
            left: "-=200px"
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            queue: false,
            step: function (now, fx) {

            },
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });

        $('.' + slideId + '_' + 'ui li img:eq(' + (this.options.index) + ')').animate({
            width: ($("." + slideId + "_ui li img").width() + 20) + "px",
            height: "88px"
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            step: function (now, fx) {

            },
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });
        this.options.index++;
        console.log(this.options.index);
    }
},
    '[class*="previous"] click': function (el, ev) {
    var cName = el.attr('class').substr(9);
    var slideId = cName.substring(0, cName.lastIndexOf("_"));
    console.log(slideId);

    if (parseInt($("." + slideId + "_ui").css("left"), 10) <= 0) {
        $('.' + slideId + '_' + 'ui').animate({
            left: "+=200px"
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            queue: false,
            step: function (now, fx) {
                //$("."+slideId+"_ui:gt(0)").css( "left", now );
                //$("."+slideId+"_ui li img").width();
                //console.log(now);
            },
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });

        $('.' + slideId + '_' + 'ui li img:eq(' + (this.options.index) + ')').animate({
            width: ($("." + slideId + "_ui li img").width() - 20) + "px",
            height: "88px"
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            step: function (now, fx) {

            },
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });
        this.options.index--;
        console.log(this.options.index);
    }
},
```

Comment: Hi ok I'm going to re-create it on this site

Comment: Hi So I have created my slider on jsfiddle.net => http://jsfiddle.net/jdDYQ/4/    Now my problem is I want to only enlarge the central picture you can see I have commented out the function to do so but it breaks my slider it as to be like the IOs album library to see. Any Ideas how to make ? Thanks

Comment: No one has a solution ?

Comment: Problem solved as no one was able to do  too difficult for them I guess. http://jsfiddle.net/jdDYQ/7/